# Give user the option to view desktop version of responsive layout

Tags: css

What is the easiest way to give users the option to view the desktop version of a website on a mobile device when using a responsive layout?

Comment: I don't see what responsiveness has to do with it. Just add a link to  the desktop version and save the preference in a cookie. Or I completely misunderstood you. If that's the case please improve your question :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give some class like responsive to your main HTML, i.e. something like:

```
<body class="responsive">
...
</body>
```

And write your CSS without the `.responsive` parent prefix for normal screens:

```
.myheading {
...
}
.mybutton {
...
}
```

Use the `.responsive` parent prefix in your media queries for smaller screens

```
@media all and (max-width: 320px) { /* example */
    .responsive .myheading {
    ...
    }
    .responsive .mybutton {
    ...
    }
}
```

When someone wants to view the big screen version, simply do:

```
$('body').removeClass('responsive');
```

and your media queries will be ignored from there on. when you want to switch back to being responsive, simply do:

```
$('body').addClass('responsive');
```

NOTE: the above solution assumes jquery, can be just as easily done even without jquery.

Comment: This is totally unfeasible for both large projects with thousands of lines of CSS and a variety of media query breakpoints to manage and also projects where some stylesheets are inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
 $('#TOGGLE').on('click', function() {
     $('meta[name="viewport"]').remove();
 });
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. But browsers ignore meta tags after the document is parsed so I don't understand how this could work?

Comment: Actually it can work, with simple cookies and javascript check.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

between `<head>` and `</head>`

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

between `<body>` and `<body>`

```
<span id="desktopswitch">desktop version</span>
```

between `<script>` and `</script>`

```
$('#desktopswitch').on('click', function() {
    $('#viewport').attr('content','width=1024, initial-scale=0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=1');
});
```

Unfortunatly it only works on the current site. To view it that way on the following sites you should query it with php.

Comment: Works with cookies! No need for php.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found very nice solution for this question. It allows to switch between 'full' and 'mobile' versions without doubling your whole css stylesheet with parent prefix. I think that suggested answer by 'techfoobar' not very simple if you have CSS for over 2000-3000 lines...
Well, First of all you must have`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in the `<head>` tag.
Then put two tags somewhere in the footer of your website

```
<span id="setvar">FULL version of website</span>
<span id="removevar">Back to mobile version</span>
```

Next add main functionality: The main idea is to store some local variable in the localstorage. It allows to keep the 'full version' on mobile device even when going to the other pages of the website. So when the user once clicked "Full version of website" it will remain "full" when he change pages of site.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

   //when we clicking on 'show full version' we are changing viewport and define local variable into the localstorage
   $("#setvar").click(function(){
      localStorage.setItem('localVar', 'exist');
      $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1024');

      //imitate toggling effect
      $(this).hide();
      $('#removevar').show();
  });

  // when we go to other pages there is checking 'if the local variable exist' - if exist then window automatically switched to full version
  if (localStorage.getItem('localVar') === 'exist') {
    $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1024');
    $('#setvar').hide();
    $('#removevar').show();
  }

  // when we click on 'Back to mobile version' we are removing local variable from localstorage and restore default viewport
   $("#removevar").click(function(){
      localStorage.removeItem('localVar', 'exist');
      $('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=device-width');
      $(this).hide();
      $('#setvar').show();
   }); 
});
</script>
```

And last - add some styles to hide this functionality on desktops

```
<style>
#removevar{
  display:none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  #setvar, #removevar{
  display:none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer, especially given the use of localstorage.